# Prevent Automatic Installation of iOS Update

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, software-update

I know that iOS devices will automatically download the latest version of iOS when it's available. A message then appears, asking if the user wants to install the update later or now.

I have 2 questions regarding this: One, if I click "later," will I receive the message again, and how frequently would I receive this message?

And two, if I restart my iOS device, would the new version of iOS be automatically installed when it turns back on?

Comment: Does that mean the iOS 9 installs automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For iOS 7 -> 8

You do not receive the message again, but the update is available through the Settings app.

Device restarts do not cause update installation.

Source: my wife's iPhone 5S, which went weeks and multiple reboots without installing 8.4

### For iOS 9

I believe iOS 9 will prompt you daily (I upgraded immediately, but I am basing this on the comments below). However, rebooting will still not cause the update to install.

Comment: So, if I click "remind me later," it will continue to remind me? Is there any way to turn off these reminders?

Comment: Go to Settings.app > General > Storage & iCloud Usage > Manage Storage and delete the auto-downloaded software update.

Comment: Will it automatically download again if I delete the auto-downloaded software update?

Comment: Mine have not thus far.

Answer (score 0):

System upgrade has nothing to do with the reboot process. No matter if it's automatically pulled and just wait for your green light to be installed. You can safely reboot your device without being worried that it will upgrade the iOS.